# I was making a Discord bot...... and i keep geting this error

Tags: discord, bots

I was making a discord bot with a 'ban' command (discord.js) and I keep getting this error.... [parsing error unexpected token case]

the script:

```
    case 'ban': {
      if (!isMod)
        return;

      let userID = args.includes('<@!') ? args.replace('<@!', '').replace('>', '')
          : args.includes('<@') ? args.replace('<@', '').replace('<', '') : '';

      if (userID == '') {
        message.reply('Invalid user ID or mention.');
        return;
      }

      message.guild.fetchMember(userID).then(member => {
        member.kick("Banned by " + message.author.tag).then(m => {
          message.channel.send(' Banned <@' + userID + '>.');
        }).catch(() => {
          console.error;
          message.reply('Could not ban the specified member.');
        });
      };
      break;
    });

User.ban({reason: banReason})
```

Comment: Are you using the `case` statement inside a `switch`?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a bracket.

```js
case 'ban': {
    if (!isMod)
        return;

    let userID = args.includes('<@!') ? args.replace('<@!', '').replace('>', '')
        : args.includes('<@') ? args.replace('<@', '').replace('<', '') : '';

    if (userID == '') {
        message.reply('Invalid user ID or mention.');
        return;
    }

    message.guild.fetchMember(userID).then(member => {
        member.kick("Banned by " + message.author.tag).then(m => {
            message.channel.send(' Banned <@' + userID + '>.');
        }).catch(() => {
            console.error;
            message.reply('Could not ban the specified member.');
        });
    });
    break;
}
```

Check before break statement - that was the problem.

Comment: I can't see your full code. maybe your ```switch``` is missing or no named method ```ban```.